# issue with filenames containing spaces when using mv/cp with xclip

Tags: linux

```
$ type xclip
xclip is aliased to 'xclip -selection clipboard'
$ xclip -o
target filename with spaces
$ mv original_filename `xclip -o`
mv: target ‘spaces’ is not a directory
```

I've tried to replace spaces with `\_` ('_' means space) first but it doesn't work either. Where did I go wrong? Thanks.

Comment: Add some quotes: `mv origin_filename "\`xclip -o\`"`, or [better yet](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/082): `mv origin_filename "$(xclip -o)"`

Comment: @Biffen Thx, Biffen. But I want to know why using xclip 'barely' is wrong?

Comment: Because the backticks are expanded by your shell into whatever the command prints. If it prints spaces they expand into spaces.

Comment: Imagine you selected the text `my file`. Then `mv original_filename \`xclip -o\`` becomes `mv original_filename my file` .  I.e. it's the same as giving 3 arguments to `mv`

Comment: @nos Then why escaping spaces first (as I mentioned in the question) still not working?

Comment: @mljli Because your ‘escaping’ backslashes will expand into literal backslashes and the spaces will still be spaces. If you want to see what actually gets executed you can run `set -x` first.

Comment: @Biffen Would you mind posting an answer so I can close this question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

<sup><sup>Turning my comments into an answer.</sup></sup>

A command in backticks gets expanded into whatever executing the command prints (to STDOUT). So:

```
mv original_filename `xclip -o`
```

Gets expanded into:

```
mv original_filename target filename with spaces
```

And *then* executed.  To group the result of `xclip -o` into a single arguments one should put quotes around it:

```
mv original_filename "`xclip -o`"
```

Thus it expands into:

```
mv original_filename "target filename with spaces"
```

Note that [backticks are deprecated](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/082) and one should use `$()` instead:

```
mv original_filename "$(xclip -o)"
```